# What is the time complexity of initializing an HashSet using a populated ArrayList?

Tags: java, performance, collections

I read online that `HashSet` uses `HashMap` as its underlying data structure.

And `HashMap` uses `ArrayList` as its underlying data structure with each item in the list being an object of `LinkedList` or a `tree`.

What is the time complexity when you initialize a `HashSet` this way? Can it be **O(1)**? If not, why?

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add(1);
list.add(3);
list.add(2);
list.add(6);
list.add(0);
HashSet<Integer> set = new HashSet<>(list);
```

Comment: Your title says `HashMap`, but your code demonstrates initializing a `HashSet`.

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out. I have updated the question.

Answer (score 4):

`HashMap` does not use an `ArrayList` as its underlying data structure.

`HashMap` maintains a hashtable built out of a primitive array, and uses a hybrid strategy of a linked list or a tree for handling collisions. You can see this by examining the [source code for `java.util.HashMap`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/util/HashMap.java).

Since, to build a hashtable, you need to invoke the hash function on every entry to determine the hash location, the minimum bound is O(N). The worst case is for pathologically distributed keys (e.g. every key is a collision), which would be substantially worse than O(N). Since the Java 8 implementation degrades to a balanced tree instead of a linked list in the worst case, your worst case runtime would be O(N log N). (In previous versions of Java, which used linear probing, I believe worst case would have been O(N²)).

Comment: The default implementation in java8 does not use probing, it uses a linked list for smallish buckets (up to ~8 items) and a tree for bigger buckets.

Comment: @k5_: so it does. It looks like the Java 8 implementation is substantially more sophisticated than Java 7 or earlier. I've updated my answer, thanks.

Comment: @DanielPryden, Thanks for the explanation. I will look into the source code.

Answer (score 2):

Your `List` can contain `n` number of Objects which might be all duplicate or all unique or mixture.

The property of a `HashSet` collection is that it contains no duplicate objects.

Therefore, the time complexity to traverse the `List` and add each object to the `HashSet` would be `O(n)`