# Want to delete some elements from a list that is existed in another list

Tags: java

I have a list suppose

```
listA=[679,890,907,780,5230,781]
```

and want to delete some elements that is existed in another

```
listB=[907,5230]
```

in minimum time complexity?

I can do this problem by using two "for loops" means O(n2) time complexity, but I want to reduce this complexity to O(nlog(n)) or O(n)?
Is it possible?

Comment: You can use `listA.removeAll(listB)`. That should be the fastest way

Comment: Hey, Thanks for your reply. It is working fine.But, I want to know the algorithm behind this. can u tell me the time complexity for this?

Comment: @karan It depends on the implementation of both your lists so we can't tell.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's possible - if one of the lists is sorted. Assuming that list A is sorted and list B is unsorted, with respective dimensions `M` and `N`, the minimum time complexity to remove all of list B's elements from list A will be `O((N+M)*log(M))`. The way you can achieve this is by binary search - each lookup for an element in list A takes `O(log(M))` time, and there are `N` lookups (one for each element in list B). Since it takes `O(M*log(M))` time to sort A, it's more efficient for huge lists to sort and then remove all elements, with total time complexity **`O((N+M)*log(M))`**.

On the other hand, if you don't have a sorted list, just use [Collection.removeAll](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#removeAll(java.util.Collection)), which has a time complexity of **`O(M*N)`** in this case. The reason for this time complexity is that `removeAll` does (by default) something like the following pseudocode:

```
public boolean removeAll(Collection<?> other)
    for each elem in this list
        if other contains elem
            remove elem from this list
```

Since `contains` has a time complexity of `O(N)` for lists, and you end up doing `M` iterations, this takes `O(M*N)` time in total.

Finally, if you want to minimize the time complexity of `removeAll` (with possibly degraded real world performance) you can do the following:

```
List<Integer> a = ...
List<Integer> b = ...
HashSet<Integer> lookup = new HashSet<>(b);
a.removeAll(lookup);
```

For bad values of b, the time to construct `lookup` could take up to time `O(N*log(N))`, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44144223/5699679) (see "pathologically distributed keys"). After that, invoking `removeAll` will take `O(1)` for `contains` over `M` iterations, taking `O(M)` time to execute. Therefore, the time complexity of this approach is **`O(M + N*log(N))`**.

So, there are three approaches here. One provides you with time complexity `O((N+M)*log(M))`, another provides you with time complexity `O(M*N)`, and the last provides you with time complexity `O(M + N*log(N))`. Considering that the first and last approaches are similar in time complexity (as `log` tends to be very small even for large numbers), I would suggest going with the naive `O(M*N)` for small inputs, and the simplest `O(M + N*log(N))` for medium-sized inputs. At the point where your memory usage starts to suffer from creating a HashSet to store the elements of B (very large inputs), I would finally switch to the more complex `O((N+M)*log(M))` approach.

You can find an AbstractCollection.removeAll implementation [here](http://developer.classpath.org/doc/java/util/AbstractCollection-source.html#line.301).

**Edit:**
The first approach doesn't work so well for ArrayLists - removing from the middle of list A takes `O(M)` time, apparently. Instead, sort list B (`O(N*log(N))`), and iterate through list A, removing items as appropriate. This takes **`O((M+N)*log(N))`** time and is better than the `O(M*N*log(M))` that you end up with when using an ArrayList. Unfortunately, the "removing items as appropriate" part of this algorithm requires that you create data to store the non-removed elements in `O(M)`, as you don't have access to the internal data array of list A. In this case, it's strictly better to go with the HashSet approach. This is because (1) the time complexity of `O((M+N)*log(N))` is actually worse than the time complexity for the HashSet method, and (2) the new algorithm doesn't save on memory. Therefore, *only use the first approach when you have a List with `O(1)` time for removal* (e.g. LinkedList) **and** a *large amount of data*. Otherwise, **use removeAll**. It's simpler, often faster, and supported by library designers (e.g. ArrayList has a [custom](http://developer.classpath.org/doc/java/util/ArrayList-source.html#line.504) `removeAll` implementation that allows it to take linear instead of quadratic time using negligible extra memory).

Comment: @daniu No worries, I realized it and fixed it :) It takes `O(M*N)` *in this case* - if the other collection is a HashSet, it'll take `O(1)` time to lookup in `M` iterations for a total time complexity of `O(M)`. Nevertheless, the asker did specify that the two collections were lists.

Comment: Thanks,It is working.Will it work when all values in list are string not integer?

Comment: @karan It should - just change `HashSet<Integer>` to `HashSet<String>`, as well as `List<Integer>` to `List<String>`.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this in following way

Sort second list( you can sort any one of the list. Here I have sorted second list). After that loop through first array and for each element of first array, do binary search in second array.

You can sort list by using **Collections.sort()** method.

Total complexity:-

For sorting :- **O(mLogm)** where m is size of second array. I have sorted only second array.

For removing :- **O(nLogm)**

Comment: You welcome. @karan you may upvote any answer if you are sure  that answer is correct. You may downvote also if you are sure that answer is wrong. Thank you.